# Getting an error when checking if a variable is null

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
var topicValue = Model.Topic;
var replaceResult = string.Empty;
if (topicValue != null & topic.Contains(topicValue)) {

}
```

My intent is for the if not to be executed if topicValue is null. However I am getting an error message saying:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Can anyone explain how I can make this work?

Comment: You could almost hear the flurry of answers come flooding in for this one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var topicValue = Model.Topic;
var replaceResult = string.Empty;
if (topicValue != null & topic.Contains(topicValue)) {

}
```

Should be

```
var topicValue = Model.Topic;
var replaceResult = string.Empty;
if (topicValue != null && topic.Contains(topicValue)) {

}
```

EDIT:

Also, where do you initialise topic? Maybe you should check for that too and it should be

```
var topicValue = Model.Topic;
    var replaceResult = string.Empty;
    if (topicValue != null && topic != null && topic.Contains(topicValue)) {

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `&&` instead of `&`. The *logical AND* operator `&` will result in both parts of the condition being executed, regardless of the result of the first part. Using the *conditional AND* operator `&&` will *only* execute the second part if the result of the first part is `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably, your `topic` itself is null, that is the reason for the exception/error.

Perform a check for `topic!=null` also.

Answer (score 2):

You are using binary operator `&` instead of logic one `&&`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the && operator as a logical AND

```
if (topicValue != null **&&** topic.Contains(topicValue)) {

}
```